# Does using the simple past without "used to/would" imply something happen just once?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

1.Your answer takes me back to my college days when I wrote an answer that would grant me not more than 3 marks, to a question that was 15 marks.

2.Your answer takes me back to my college days when I **used to/would** write answers that would grant me not more than 3 marks, to questions that were 15 marks.

Do both the sentences mean the same thing? Does **wrote** imply the speaker wrote such an answer just once, whereas **would/ used to** imply they might have written such an answer many a time?

Like if I said "I **used to** ride a bicycle as a kid", or "I **used to** ride a bicycle when I was a kid", it would clearly mean that as a kid I rode a bicycle more than once, right? But if I said "I rode a bicycle when I was a kid",  would the implication remain I rode it more than once?

Comment: Your first (explicitly singular) version *could* validly be used by a careful native speaker when he actually intended the "repeatedly, habitually" implications. It's just not really the *default* interpretation. But this isn't really to do with whether you include ***used to*** or ***would*** - if you change #1 to plural *...when I wrote **answers** that would...,* you immediately force the "habitual" interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Shouldn't be "your answer **took** me back .."? I mean, the narrator here is describing an emotion or feeling he/she experienced for a short period of time right after seeing the answer?

Comment: @Cardinal: It largely depends on how long ago it was when some answer reminded me of *much* earlier experiences, and whether I *still* feel that connection. It's a pretty crude "rule of thumb", but I'd probably use Present Tense ***takes*** if the addressee's answer had that effect on me *sometime earlier within the day when I was speaking*, but switch to Past Tense ***took*** if I'd slept since being thus affected by the answer (***and*** if it was no longer having that "reminiscence" effect on me at time of utterance).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Yes, *I rode a bicycle when I was a kid* implies a habitual activity. I think this is because *ride a bicycle* and *ride a horse* can refer to having those skills, not necessarily to always riding one particular bike or horse.

On the other hand, *I wrote an answer* has to mean one particular answer.